# Is there a stable device internet adress?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating a website using HTML (no visual editors at all - please do not suggest me one), and I want to add an accounts system. I have already made an example database, a signup/login form but I wonder about something. Is there a stable address that can be received and processed, and every device has one? I am asking this because I also want to make a connections table where all the devices' addresses will be located, along with the account they are linked to.

Is there a way to receive this address, and keep it even after the browser, device, and everything is closed?

If it is, please tell me. I prefer pure JavaScript, but, if there is only a way to do it in jQuery, then, I'll have to learn jQuery :(.

Comment: Are you asking how to host a server that can be accessed from anywhere? You probably don't want to host it on your own machine--make an account on glitch.com and fire up a Node/Express app that can host your database and serve your HTML and JS at a public URL. If the database needs to live on your machine, self-hosting a server is a huge topic and out of scope for this site.

Comment: By stable, you mean a non-changing address for every device?

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique stable identifier for each device or user (unless you generate one, and store it in e.g. local storage/cookies, and even then it could always be removed by the user and you'd regenerate one).

You seem to be looking for cookies, though, if you want to keep an user logged in on their device after having created an account.